# Suicide is now the number one cause for teenagers from 12 to 18

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does the following sentence mean in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IawjKuNVm2Q) at 01.14.

> Suicide is now the number one **cause** for teenagers from 12 to 18.

And he adds:

> It hurts everyone inside, but they're not doing something.

Is it clear for you whom he refers by "they"?

Cause can mean a long-term belief like your values and you can fight for it or it can mean a reason of something. However, either usage does not makes a sense for me for this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It can also [mean](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cause)

> something that brings about an effect or a result

The second sentence is a bit sloppy, but "they" refers to "everyone" and means "people in general."

Comment: Thank you. When I looked at the definition 1b on the link you gave , it means reason of something as I mentioned in my question and  it says "...cause of the accident". However, in the original text, there is no result or cause of something. Does  he imply death among teenagers?

Comment: Yes,"of death" is implied.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker made a mistake in speech. He meant to say "Suicide is the number one cause **of death** for teenagers from 12 to 18."

If he had mentioned causes of death in the previous sentence, the words could be omitted, but he didn't, so I think it's simply a mistake due to nervousness.

Comment: Or there was a sentence before this that was left out. Which seems a lot more likely to me.

Comment: @gnasher729 Do you mean that it was edited out of the video? That doesn't seem too likely.